# Why is my code evaluating before I even reference it

Tags: java

I have a class called Logger and I want to implement the following method. I want to understand why does it keeps giving me add 1 when I didn't even call upon it.

```java
public class Logger<T> {
    private final T elem;
    private final String log;

    public Logger(T elem, String log) {
        this.elem = elem;
        this.log = log;
    }

    public Logger(T elem) {
        this(elem, "");
    }

    public T get(){
        return elem;
    }

    static <U> Logger<U> of(U elem) {
        Optional<U> ele = Optional.<U>ofNullable(elem);
        if (elem instanceof Logger) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("already a Logger");
        }
        if (ele == Optional.empty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument cannot be null");
        }
        return new Logger<U>(elem);
    }

    <U> Logger<U> map(Function<? super T, ? extends U> mapper) {
        U ele = mapper.apply(this.elem);
        String log = this.elem + " -> " + ele;
        String resultant = this.log.equals("") ?
                log :
                this.log + "\n" + log;
        return new Logger<U>(ele, resultant);
    }

    <U> Logger<U> flatMap(Function<? super T, ? extends Logger<? extends U>> mapper) {
        Logger<? extends U> ds = mapper.apply(elem);
        String logs = !log.equals("") ?
                this.log + "\n" + ds.log :
                ds.log;
        return new Logger<>(ds.elem, logs);
    }
    
    public Logger<T> test(Predicate<? super T> pred, Logger<T> trueLogger, Logger<T> falseLogger) {
        if (pred.test(elem)) {
            return trueLogger;
        } else {
            return falseLogger;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Logger)) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.elem == ((Logger<?>) obj).elem && this.log.equals(((Logger<?>) obj).log);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String loggerElem = "Logger[" + elem + "]";
        return !log.equals("") ? loggerElem + "\n" + log : loggerElem;
    }

}
```

However, when I input

```java
Logger<Integer> five = Logger.<Integer>of(5);
five.map(x -> x + 1).test(x -> x == 5,
                          five.map(x -> { System.out.println("add 1"); return x + 1; }),
                          five.map(x -> { System.out.println("sub 1"); return x - 1; }));
```

it will return me

```
add 1
sub 1
$... ==> Logger[4]
5 -> 4
```

instead of

```
sub 1
$... ==> Logger[4]
5 -> 4
```

I tried removing the bottom part and just returning null but... it still prints out add 1 and sub 1 which is really puzzling me since I did not even call them.

Comment: Why do you expect `five.map()` to execute lazily when you put it as an argument, but immediately when you call it straight-out? Have you considered  having it so that the `.test()` method has you pass the `predicateForTrue` and `predicateForFalse`, and do the `five.map()` inside the engine with the given predicate?

Comment: Not so sure what that other commentor wanted but here is the entire code

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Sorry I don't quite get it

Comment: There's no main method, so it's not a [mcve]... we could do with something we could just copy, paste, compile and run - with no extraneous methods.

Comment: Both of `Logger.map` are always called to produce arguments for `Logger.test`, and inside the `Logger.map`, you will always call the `mapper.apply`, which executes both functions that print "add 1" and "sub1". You need to think of and implement some way of not using your input functions and instead possibly save them to be executed only when the actual log printing is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to lazy evaluate the arguments of the test method.

```
    public Logger<T> test(Predicate<? super T> pred,
            Supplier<Logger<T>> trueLogger, Supplier<Logger<T>> falseLogger) {
        if (pred.test(elem)) {
            return trueLogger.get();
        } else {
            return falseLogger.get();
        }
    }
```

and

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger<Integer> five = Logger.<Integer>of(5);
    five.map(x -> x + 1).test(x -> x == 5,
        () -> five.map(x -> { System.out.println("add 1"); return x + 1; }),
        () -> five.map(x -> { System.out.println("sub 1"); return x - 1; }));
}
```

output:

```
sub 1
```

Comment: Unfortuntely the method must start with `public Logger<T> test(Predicate<? super T> pred, Logger<T> trueLogger, Logger<T> falseLogger) ` and test input cannot be changed.